# Array out of order after sort in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a Java String array containing the values 1-10. When I run Arrays.sort() on it however, it becomes 1, 10, 2, 3, 4...9. Does anyone know why the 10 is out of order? Is it because its a string array instead of an int array? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Yes, for the same reason that "at" is before "b" in the dictionary.

Comment: The `sort()` method sorts string in alphabet order, and "10" is not converting to 10.

Comment: "Is it because its a string array instead of an int array?" yes. Do you remember how words in dictionary are ordered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this happens because it's array of Strings. 
Default sorting for String type - simple Unicode ordering is similar to alphabetical sorting. That's why your result looks like that.

If you change type to int, everything should be fine.

Comment: Or use a custom `Comparator`.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.sort()`'s sorting algorithm is set by its content's [natural ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) (the content's implementation of the Comparable interface).

You can check a class' sort by going to the Java documentation and checking the class' implementation. For example, String's implementation (under [`String.compareTo(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)) specifies that this is done by [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) (more commonly known as alphabetical order).

In order to fix this issue, add leading 0's to your other numbers, or use a different content type (like `int`).